# When to use @State vs @Published

Tags: swift, swiftui, mvvm

I feel like this is a question that would have already been asked somewhere, but I can't find much on it.

When using a variable for the purpose of updating the UI, when/why would we use `@State` within our view as opposed to using `@Published` within a ViewModel?

This is in the context of me trying to grasp MVVM architecture. I understand the difference generally, just not when it comes to something that both could easily accomplish the same way.

Below, I have 2 examples that do the same thing, but one uses `@State` while the other uses `@Published` and a ViewModel. Is one approach better than the other (for updating the UI purposes?)

`@State` example:

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @State var backgroundIsRed = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if backgroundIsRed {
                Color.red
            } else {
                Color.green
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture { backgroundIsRed.toggle() }

    }
}
```

`@Published` example:

```swift
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var backgroundIsRed = false
}

struct MyView: View {

    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if viewModel.backgroundIsRed {
                Color.red
            } else {
                Color.green
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture { viewModel.backgroundIsRed.toggle() }
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically, `SwiftUI` was designed with the `MVVM` approach in mind - that said, many developers decide to skip the `ViewModel` and go directly from their Model to their View. It depends on your viewpoint - this [article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/introducing-mvvm-into-your-swiftui-project) talks about implimenting MVVM, while [this post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/699003) speaks against it.

Comment: What is your source for “SwiftUI was designed with MVVM in mind”?

Comment: In your example, there is little difference except that the view model version necessitates making an additional class (for the view model). It offers no benefit, so I’d opt for the State version.

Comment: @jnpdx thanks, feel free to make it an answer.

Comment: Your example is overly simplified, since the property is used _and_ updated in the view the State property wrapper is the obvious choice but there are so many more uses cases/scenarios where the situation is more complex so it’s pointless to draw any conclusions here.

Comment: Joakim Danielson, thanks, and you're right, there are many other use cases, but I'm only referring to variables regarding the view and only the view. Why is @State the obvious choice here?

Comment: If it is only the view that reads and writes this property then why involve another type in the logic/flow since it is clearly so internal to the view?

Comment: Good point, I should clarify. While I simplified the example, most apps using MVVM will have another type/class/ViewModel already created for some other function. So, with both the view and the type created, the variable could either be placed in the view or the type/class that already exists, for whatever purpose. I'm wondering which, if it even matters.

Comment: Just be consistent in your choices. There's no right or wrong. It can get nasty if the code is spread out too much and different classes sharing a similar purpose. If there's a viewModel already, make use of it.

Comment: I agree that consistency is key but again if a property serves no purpose in a view model then why have it there?

Comment: Well it does serve a purpose, to modify the view...

Answer (score 4):

For example, I would say that the "Published" approach helps you create a test structure for your VM.

Taking your example, you could create a protocol:

```
protocol ViewModelProtocol {
   var backgroundIsRed: Bool { get }
   var date: Date { get } // Created for example purposes
}
```

And then:

```
class ViewModel: ViewModelProtocol, ObservableObject {
    @Published var backgroundIsRed = false
    @Published var date = Date()
}

class ViewModelMock: ViewModelProtocol, ObservableObject {
    @Published var backgroundIsRed = true
    @Published var date = Mock.Date
}

struct MyView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModelProtocol = ViewModel()
    //@StateObject var viewModel: ViewModelProtocol = ViewModelMock()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if viewModel.backgroundIsRed {
                Color.red
            } else {
                Color.green
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture { viewModel.backgroundIsRed.toggle() }
    }
}
```

On the other hand, the State approach presents a more straightforward way to implement the logic.

Apart from that, there isn't any particular reason to think that one is better than the other.
Hope this helps you choose which one you should use in each situation.

Answer (score 2):

`@State` and `@Published` serve different purposes in SwiftUI:

- `@State`: This property wrapper is used to declare state information within a SwiftUI view. It's typically used for local state within a view, meaning data that is relevant only to that specific view and doesn't need to be shared across multiple views or persisted beyond the lifetime of the view. `@State` is useful for managing things like whether a button is currently pressed, the current selection in a picker, or whether a modal is presented.
- `@Published`: This property wrapper is used in conjunction with the ObservableObject protocol to create observable objects. It's commonly used in SwiftUI apps with the MVVM pattern to represent the ViewModel layer. `@Published` is used to expose properties from the ViewModel that the View observes for changes. When a property marked with @Published changes, it automatically triggers the view to update any affected parts of its UI.

---

When to use each:

- Use `@State` for managing simple, view-specific state that doesn't need to be shared with other views or persisted.
- Use `@Published` within a ViewModel when you have data that needs to be shared across multiple views or needs to persist beyond the lifetime of a single view.

In summary, @State is used for managing local, view-specific state, while `@Published` is used for managing shared state and facilitating communication between views and their associated ViewModels.

---

So, Example 1 might be considered better if the state is very localized and simple. Example 2 is better if you anticipate needing to share this state with other views or if you prefer to follow a more structured architectural pattern like MVVM.

Answer (score -2):

We don't need MVVM in SwiftUI because the `View` struct is already the view model, i.e. it holds the data that SwiftUI uses to create/update/remove the actual `UIView` objects on screen. If you use actual objects to do this job then you add unnecessary layer of indirection and will get the kind of consistency bugs that SwiftUI's clever use of value semantics was designed to eliminate.

It's best to think of `@StateObject` as `@State` but for when you need a reference type, e.g. you want to asynchronously load/save/sync data. Which is not very often nowadays given we have the much more powerful `.task` modifier.

If your aim is to group related vars and have testable logic simply use `@State var` with a custom struct which is much simpler than getting a `@StateObject` implementation correct. However, you must learn `mutating func` for your logic first. Also, if you want to access `@Environment` inside the custom struct you need to learn `DynamicProperty`.